# Master Detail Flow Android Animation API

Tags: android, animation, android-actionbar, master-detail, android-actionbar-compat

I recently saw a lot of Apps that have some kind of `MasterDetailFlow`. The YouTube App for example has three horizontal lines topLeft on its Action Bar triggering an Animation which shows a Layout on its left side. You could also swipe this View inside with a left-to-right touch gesture. Same (without gesture) applies in the new GoolgeMaps App. I added a screenshot for claryfication:

[image: Detail Only]
[image: Master-Detail]

Since these Apps use the same Icon for it to trigger and other (non-google-apps) are using the same, and the style of it seems the same, I suspect that there must be an API for it. If I create an Activity using `MasterDetailFlow` Macro, they are not animated. depending on ScreenSize they are either shown or not. I couldn't find an API Method to trigger it. Has Anyone a clue how this is getting implemented? If they do anything on their own a short 'you must handle it yourself' answer is enaugh.

Comment: That's a `DrawerLayout` and for the icon you would use an http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html

Comment: put it as answer (maybe with a helpful link for fellow users) and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I recently saw a lot of Apps that have some kind of MasterDetailFlow.

Nothing in this question involves the master-detail pattern. The master-detail design pattern is for presenting a collection of things (contacts, photos, restaurants, books, whatever) and details of a selected item out of the collection.

> The YouTube App for example has three horizontal lines topLeft on its Action Bar triggering an Animation which shows a Layout on its left side.

This is [the navigation drawer design pattern](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html), sometimes referred to as a "sliding menu".

> Has Anyone a clue how this is getting implemented?

The Android Support package [has `DrawerLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html) for this (also covered [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)), and there are third party sliding menu implementations as well.